# Findmax() method returns second highest value when first element of array is the highest

Tags: c++, pointers, max

This findMax function returns max value from the array only if it is located at some index other than first index. I don't understand why because my findMin function that has almost the same code works perfectly fine.

```
void findMax(int array[5])
{
    maximum = array; 
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    if (*(array+i) > *maximum)
        *maximum = *(array+i);
    }
    cout<<"Maximum element in the array is "<< *maximum << "\n" ;
}
```

This is my findMin fun that is working fine.

```
void findMin(int array[5])
{
    minimum = array;    
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    if (*(array+i) < *minimum)
        *minimum = *(array+i);
    }
    cout<<"Minimum element in the array is "<< *minimum <<"\n";
}
```

Comment: is maximum & minimum global variables?

Comment: @AshwinSubramanya yes they are

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have described how to do this more cleanly in C++. But to point out the actual bug: it's in this line.

```
    *maximum = *(array+i);
```

You're not reassigning the `maximum` pointer to *point to* the maximum element, but rather you're never changing the pointer, but changing the value inside the array where `maximum` points to (i.e. `array[0]`). You meant this instead:

```
    maximum = array + i;
```

The same issue is present in your `findMin` function as well.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. I've changed that too and it's working fine.

Comment: @Thomas I would add that for the last 5 years it is not customary to use pointers in explicit form

Comment: @Beeen007 Make that 20 years, at least. That's why I said the other answers were cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as one of the comments on your question said this is mostly C way of doing things. In C++ you should use `std::vector`, `std::min_element` and `std::max_element`. It's easier and safer to use them instead of doing everything manually by yourself.

But, if you really want to do it yourself, try this code out, it should work:

```
void findMax(int array[])
{
    maximum = array;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (*(array + i) > *maximum)
            maximum = (array + i);
    }
    cout << "Maximum element in the array is " << *maximum << "\n";
}

void findMin(int array[])
{
    minimum = array;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (*(array + i) < *minimum)
            minimum = (array + i);
    }
    cout << "Minimum element in the array is " << *minimum << "\n";
}
```

This should work assuming that `minimum` and `maximum` are globally declared like this:

```
int * maximum;
int * minimum;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are minmax_element tools for finding maximum and minimum, this is the most optimal variant of solving your problem - see the definition of the StdMinMax function.
But if you want to implement the logic yourself, I gave an example of a function, see the definition of the MinMax function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


void StdMinMax(int* arr, const unsigned int size)
{
    std::pair<int*, int*> bounds = std::minmax_element(arr, arr + size); // or use auto bounds = ... ore auto [max, min] = ...

    std::cout << "min : " << *bounds.first << " max : " << *bounds.second << std::endl;

}


void MinMax(int* arr, const unsigned int size)
{
    std::cout << "Find max : " << std::endl;

    auto currentMax = *arr;
    for (int i = 1 ; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] > currentMax)
        {
            currentMax = arr[i];
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Max : " << currentMax << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Find min : " << std::endl;

    auto currentMin = *arr;
    for (int i = 1 ; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] < currentMax)
        {
            currentMin = arr[i];
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Min : " << currentMin << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    const unsigned int size{5};

    int array[size]{1, 3, 4, -11, 77};

    StdMinMax(array, size);

    MinMax(array, size);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm a beginner so I try things that I understand but I'll sure check it. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Maha K Try reading any C++ stl book, and don't use pointers in explicit form ))